# aligning css grids in one line

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a grid layout with two boxes that I want to be in one line.

the result was :

[image]

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "1 2 2";
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: aqua;
  grid-area: 1;
  height: 50vh;
}

.content {
  background-color: black;
  grid-area: 2;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

why it doesn't follow the template I designated

Comment: correct numbers can't be used as grid-area. Besides that, It would be easier to simply use flexbox for such task.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use numbers you need to prefix them with `\3` but I don't really recommend

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "1 2 2";
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: aqua;
  grid-area: \31;
  height: 50vh;
}

.content {
  background-color: black;
  grid-area: \32;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can use unescaped numbers as grid area names.

Just use letters instead.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "a b b"
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: aqua;
  grid-area: a;
  height: 50vh;
}

.content {
  background-color: black;
  grid-area: b;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
  </div>
  <div class="content"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: you're right, I didn't pay attention. thank you